# I have more than IZK current running through a Zener diode, but the voltage drop is below its Zener voltage, what does this mean?

Tags: transistors

I'm supplying more than enough voltage, I am however using a transistor which may have complicated issues. The voltage drop should be at least 4.1 for that diode. Having problems with multiple models regardless or what resistance is set. Have I just connected it incorrectly?

[image]

https://postimg.cc/5Xnv181d

Comment: Show your circuit, marked with voltages and currents.

Comment: I can see the issue quite clearly (took about 10 seconds). Add up the forward voltage of the LED and a base emitter junction. Note: in reality, the LED would probably become a SED (smoke emitting diode) and Q1 might well lose the magic smoke.

Comment: I don't see the schematic… also it's talking about a transistor and a zener? no idea of what's happening

Comment: @PeterSmith Apparently I dont understand basic electronics. I added another picture and simplified everything remvoing the transistor, and Im still not getting a proper drop over the zener diode. I thought leds didnt care too much what voltage they received and were current driven devices so it isnt receiving too much voltage?

Comment: LEDs are extremely voltage-sensitive. They are, after all, diodes, and have an exponential voltage/current curve. Typically, a red LED will have a forward bias of about 2 volts. I suggest you put another voltmeter across your LED. With about 2 volts on the LED the base of the transistor will be (more or less) 2.7 volts. This in turn suggests that you should add another ammeter to see how much current the LED is drawing - I suspect you will be surprised.

Answer (score 6):

Here is your effective circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgtvdv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage at the emitter of Q1 is going to be about 2.4V (the typical forward voltage of many red LEDs) and the voltage at the base of Q1 will be about 0.7V above that (so about 3.1V). Note that the 10K resistor is not doing anything meaningful.

So there would be about 3.1V across the zener, implying 3.9V across 200 ohms = 19.5mA, the majority of which is going into the base of Q1.

The zener voltage simply cannot exceed those limits provided something does not short out (which it will). In this circuit, because the current is not limited in any way, a *large* amount of current will flow. Eventually it will apply about 3.5V across the LED directly (assuming Q1 does not short out), which would be destructive.

If you wish to simply turn on your LED, there are simpler ways without a zener.

Answer (score 2):

Your LED is connected incorrectly. It should not be in parallel to R2, but rather connected to the transistor collector.

Comment: Sorry, but how does this have anything to do with the zener voltage?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It does have a lot to do with it. The voltage drop across the LED + R2 in series would be much higher. It's the forward voltage of the LED + Vbe of Q1 that's limiting the voltage applied to the Zener.

Comment: @TooTea My point is that all of that information should be added to the answer. The OP is clearly inexperienced and needed a more complete explanation. This was the very first answer and it said nothing about the zener voltage.

Answer (score 2):

So, just to light up a LED buffering with a transistor the circuit should be simplified to:

- a LED with a series resistor R1 to limit the current (10 ohm give here about 20 mA, for less increase R1);
- a zener with the right voltage threshold to bias the LED ad allow the VBE voltage drop (here e.g. 3.6V-(2.7V+0.7V) = 0.2V);
- the supply can be 5V with margin;
- then the transistor can be driven by the control signal to switch on and off the LED; if no driving signal, a resistor can be added and connected to the supply (permanently on). For the driving signal you can provide a series resistor feeding the base for protection but is usually not needed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f022lC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have already addressed what's wrong with the circuit, so the last missing bit is: **Why do you see current through the diode far below the rated Zener voltage?**

And the answer to that is: **Because this is not an ideal Zener diode.**

1N53 is a series of power Zeners (rated to 5 W continuous), so 1 mA is virtually nothing for such a diode. Looking at [the datasheet](https://cz.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1N5333B_D-1801430.pdf), you can see (on page 2) that the nominal Zener voltage of 1N5336 is specified for a Zener current of 290 mA. Figure 7 (on page 5, fourth curve from the left) then tells you that you should expect about 9 mA of reverse current at 3 volts. Your simulated part is thus actually a bit more ideal than the real thing.